# Formatting data before render it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am displaying some data in the view, but I need to formatted first, I was doing something like

`val.toFixed(2)` and that is OK, it works but the problem is that `val` sometimes comes with letters, and `toFixed(2)` is not taking that into account so is not displaying the letters.

So I need something that takes into account letters and numbers, the letters don't have to change, only the numbers which comes like `234235.345345435`, and obviously I need it like this `234235.34`.

Here is some of the code I am using

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat='header in headers'>{{header.th}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat='data in headers'>
          <div ng-repeat='inner in data.td'>
            <span ng-repeat='(prop, val) in inner'>{{val.toFixed(2)}}</span>
          </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and in the controller

```
$scope.LoadMyJson = function() {
      for (var s in myJson){
        $scope.data.push(s);
        if ($scope.headers.length < 1) 
            for (var prop in myJson[s]){
            prop.data = [];
            $scope.headers.push({th:prop, td: []});
          }
      }
      for (var s in $scope.data){
        for (var prop in $scope.headers){
            var header = $scope.headers[prop].th;
              var data = myJson[$scope.data[s]][header];                         
                 $scope.headers[prop].td.push(data);
                 console.log($scope.headers[prop].td);
        }
      }
};
```

and I prepared [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tt7kb9j6/)

the way it is right now, is displaying the table properly, but as you see, the table is missing the `name`, it is because of the `toFixed` method.

So, what can I do ?

Comment: Use `{{ typeof val === 'number' ? val.toFixed(2) : val }}`

Comment: @Tushar `Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 24-24 [?] in expression [typeof val === 'number' ? val.toFixed(2) : val].`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09) to use on your template.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th ng-repeat='header in headers'>{{header.th}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat='data in headers'>
          <div ng-repeat='inner in data.td'>
            <span ng-repeat='(prop, val) in inner'>{{val|formatValue}}</span>
          </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


angular.module('whatever').filter('formatValue', function () {
  return function (value) {
    if (isNaN(parseFloat(value))) {
      return value;
    }

    return parseFloat(value).toFixed(2);
  } 
});
```

Comment: I am getting an error, try here, I just implement the filter: http://jsfiddle.net/gx236zdq/

Comment: I just updated the plunker and the answer with the fix.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

That is a clean way to render formated data in view using angularjs as MVC
frontend framework :

- Create a filter in your angular application.
- Include your filter in your index.html.
- use your filter like this : {{somedata | filterName}}

That is a simple angular filter to solve your problem, hope it will help you :

```
angular.module('app')
.filter('formatHeader', function() {
    return function(data) {

        if(angular.isNumber(data)) {
            return data.toFixed(2);
        }

        return data;
    }
});
```

And us it like this :

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th ng-repeat='header in headers'>{{header.th}}</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td ng-repeat='data in headers'>
      <div ng-repeat='inner in data.td'>
        <span ng-repeat='(prop, val) in inner'>{{val | formatHeader}}</span>
      </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

You can take a look about these references :

- [angular functions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function)
- [filter doc.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)
- [angular tutorials](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09)