# ng-repeat return 0 instead of NaN

Tags: angularjs, nan

In using `ng-repeat` to display table rows, I do a calculation of one of the values on-the-fly.  If the denominator of the calculation is 0, I get `Nan` (obviously).  The usual methods of returning a 0 instead of `NaN` don't seem to work.

Here's my view HTML:

```
<tr ng-repeat="metricRow in tierData.metrics track by $index " ng-click="rowClick(metricRow)">
      <td ng-switch="key" ng-repeat="(key,val) in metricsHeaders " ng-if="val.exposed" ng-class="{'text-field': val.type == 'text'}">
        <div ng-switch-when="headline">
          <b>{{metricRow.headline}}</b><br/>
          {{metricRow.description_1}}<br/>
          {{metricRow.description_2}}<br/>
          <a href="{{metricRow.url}}" target="_blank">link</a>
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="click_through_rate">
          {{((metricRow.clicks/metricRow.impressions).toFixed(2) || 0) + "%"}} <!-- here's the problem -->
        </div>
        <div ng-switch-default>
          {{metricRow[key]}}
        </div>

      </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: To many logic on the template. Create a filter that will do the needed transformation

Comment: Are you implying that there is no way to do this in the template?

Comment: Maybe there is but  it is hard to read and you might want to check for the NaN value. This will be more easily written in a filter. More over you could reuse between templates. I think this example is very simmilar to yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995509/formatting-data-before-render-it/34995718?noredirect=1#comment57719719_34995718

Comment: Thanks.  That did the trick.  If you want points you should post an answer.

Comment: That's ok, just glad to help.